# Layer-list item stroke acts as solid

Tags: android, stroke, layer-list

I have a layer-list:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        android:shape="oval"
        >
        <size android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/background_light"/>
        </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

On 4.2.2 and above it creates a white circle with a black border.

Below 4.2.2 it creates a black circle.

Is there any way to get it working below 4.2.2? Am I missing something?

My goal would be to get it work from api14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well eventually I found my own answer:

the trick is, you don't create a new item for the border, you add it to the solid shape, and it work's from api14. Like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
  <shape android:shape="oval">
    <size android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/background_light"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
  </shape>
</item>
```

actually in this case you don't even need a layer-list, but I have some other shapes in there, so that's why I'm using it. This way you can change the background color, and it still has a nice border to it.

Comment: Very helpful except you no longer need the layer-list in the example above. Just a shape will do.